# How to read Android platform key signature programmatically

Tags: android

I need to read the signature of the platform key, which signed the whole build on the device.
Currently, I can read the signature of an arbitrary package like `com.android.systemui` etc. However, due to some custom ROMs, no package is guaranteed to be installed as a part of the system.

So, my question: is there a way to read the signing signature of the system on Android devices programmatically?

---

Note: I am not trying to read the key itself. Signature, or its hash is sufficient for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help: https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/47da058112cee0b70442bcd0370c1e46e830c66b/media/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/PackageValidator.kt

Use "android" as the package name.

```
private val packageManager: PackageManager = ...

fun getSystemSignature(): ByteArray? {
    return getSignature("android")
}

@Suppress("Deprecation")
private fun getPackageInfo(clientPackageName: String): PackageInfo? {
    return when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU -> {
            val flags = PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES or PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                clientPackageName,
                PackageManager.PackageInfoFlags.of(flags.toLong()),
            )
        }

        else -> {
            val flags = PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES or PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                clientPackageName,
                flags,
            )
        }
    }
}

@Suppress("Deprecation")
private fun getSignature(packageName: String): ByteArray? {
    return when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P -> {
            getPackageInfo(packageName)
                ?.signingInfo?.signingCertificateHistory?.get(0)?.toByteArray()
        }

        else -> {
            getPackageInfo(packageName)?.signatures?.get(0)?.toByteArray()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I could search, no API exists for this purpose. Accepting the answer until I find one or they create one. Also note, there are ~5 different signing keys during AOSP signing. And above was the one I needed back on then.